# status code 302 when fetching images

Tags: photo-gallery, http-status-code-302

I've made a simple html website with *bxslider* component for a gallery but the images from it keep giving me a 302 response. they are camera pictures. thing is that i have other images that are not on the *bxslider* and not camera pictures and they load fine. when i put one of those in the gallery, they load fine too. when i open the html file, the images load fine too. im using *filezilla* to upload the website and im absolutely sure the links are right and the images are there. the images are 1000x750px and weigh about 300kb. also, when i try to load them outside the bxslider, they dont load too. i tried making the images incredibly smaller like 10x7px and still the same error. a friend said it was something about the color pallet or whatever and i changed it to rgb on *photoshop* though i may not have done it correctly, if you try to check it, the image is sam_8140.jpg. the website is: http://mheuter.besaba.com/

i wont show any code as its only html and it can be viewed in the website.

Comment: 302 status is used for a redirect. Your requests are redirecting to a page with next content: <p>The document has moved <a href="http://error.hostinger.eu/?">here</a>.</p> 

hard to say why. Probably some handler or configuration of web server do this.

Comment: how to resolve it? should i post them on another server and reference it on the website or should it be possible to fix it with the server?

Comment: I think you should check it with your hosting provider, maybe they will give you more input.

Comment: ive just sent them an email. i chose stackoverflow coz the responses are usually very fast.

Comment: hey ntl, make an answer and ill mark it. ive changed the server of the images and now its fully working.

Comment: congrats! I've created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 status is used for a redirect. Your requests are redirecting to a page with next content:

The document has moved here.

; hard to say why. Probably some handler or configuration of web server do this.

I think you should check it with your hosting provider maybe this issue is on their side.